# Not able to see Accept button for Case

Tags: lightning, lightninglistview

Not able to see Accept button for Case while using below code:-

```
<lightning:listView objectApiName="Case" listName="XYZ_queue" showActionBar="true">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and make an [edit] so that your post has a specific, well-defined question so that the community can answer.